# How to use knitr to get overlay animations in latex beamer?

Tags: latex, knitr, beamer

In latex beamer you can write the following to obtain overlay animations:

```latex
\begin{overprint}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%
    \only<\x>{%
      \includegraphics{figure/plot-\x.pdf}
    }
  }
\end{overprint}
```

How can I get `knitr` to produce such output and use overlay animations?

PS: I am aware of `fig.out='animate'` but it only works with Acrobat whereas I want a universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to write a `chunk_hook` that scans the chunk output and adds the overprint environment as well as the `\only<i>` parts around each plot:

Here is the hook:

```r
library(stringi)
overlay_hook = function(x, options) {
  x = knitr:::.chunk.hook.tex(x, options)
  if (!is.null(options$overlay_start)) {
    ind_matches = stri_locate_all_regex(x, "\\\\includegraphics")[[1]]
    stri_sub_all(x, from = ind_matches[,2]+1, length = 0) = 
      paste0("<", seq_len(nrow(ind_matches)) + options$overlay_start - 1 ,">")
  }
  return(x)
}
knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = overlay_hook)
```

To use it, you have to set `overlay_start` to a value (e.g. 1 if it should start with the first animation step)

```r
<<plot, results='hide', overlay_start = 1, fig.height=3>>=
for (i in 1:3)
  plot(function(x) x^i)
@
```